# Regex matching a line and some lines before if line starts with a specific char

Tags: python, python-re

I am processing an electronic circuit netlist in python and I am attempting to match all of a certain type of cell. Cell instantiations in a spice file can span multiple lines by using "+". For example...

**(example 1):**

```
instance_name_here pin1 pin2 pin3
+ pin4 pin5 my_cell_name_here
```

**is equivalent to (example 2):**

```
instance_name_here pin1 pin2 pin3 pin4 pin5 my_cell_name_here
```

Say my spice file has 30 of these cells, some of which are all on one line like example 1, some are on two lines like example 2, or some can even be on as many as 7 lines (if I have a "+" after each net)!

I want to match all different ways the cell with name "my_cell_name_here" could appear.

Right now I know how to match my cell if it appears on one line. Basically, my match returns all lines that end in my_cell_name_here. see as follows:

`mymatch = re.findall(".*" + my_cell_name_here + "$", spicenetlist,flags=re.MULTILINE)`

I am not sure how I should approach looking backwards. I tried the following:

`mymatch = re.findall("(.*\n\+)*" + ".*" + voltage_cell_name + "$", spicenetlist,flags=re.MULTILINE)`

That produced output worse than what I had before...
I was expecting match = anything+newline+"+"+ a line that ends with voltage_cell_name.
Instead when I printed the match I got as follows: ['','','']
any suggestions would be appreciated.

edit: I implemented something similar to Swifty's answer (not using regex).

```
def get_all_instantiations(cell_name,netlist):
    """returns a list of strings of all instantiations of a cell EXACTLY as they appear
    i.e. multiline instances using \"+\" are returned exactly as they appear"""
    cell_instantiations_list = list()
    netlist_lines = netlist.splitlines()
    index=0
    while index<len(netlist_lines):
        if netlist_lines[index].endswith(cell_name):
            cell_instantiation = netlist_lines[index]
            temp_index = index
            while netlist_lines[temp_index].startswith('+'):
                temp_index = temp_index - 1
                cell_instantiation = netlist_lines[temp_index] + "\n" + cell_instantiation
            cell_instantiations_list.insert(0,cell_instantiation)
        index = index + 1
    return cell_instantiations_list
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's feasible with a regex; but you could loop through all lines, keeping a copy of the previous line in a string, and if the current line begins with "+" append it to said string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, which produces the desired result as far as I can tell. It doesn't use regex though, so it might not be the answer you seek.

```
text = '''
instance_name_here pin1 pin2 pin3
+ pin4 pin5 my_cell_name_here
instance_name_here pin11 pin12 pin13 pin14 pin15 my_cell_name_here
instance_name_here pin21
+ pin22 pin23
+ pin 24
+ pin 25
+ my_cell_name_here
'''
lines = text.splitlines()
lastline = ''
for line in lines:
    if line.endswith("here"):
        if line.startswith('+'):
            lastline += line[1:]
            print(lastline)
        else:
            print(line)
    elif line.startswith('+'):
        lastline += line[1:]
    else:
        lastline = line
```

Output:

```
# instance_name_here pin1 pin2 pin3 pin4 pin5 my_cell_name_here
# instance_name_here pin11 pin12 pin13 pin14 pin15 my_cell_name_here
# instance_name_here pin21 pin22 pin23 pin 24 pin 25 my_cell_name_here
```

Comment: Thank you Swifty for the response. My desired approach was regex since it would provide for more concise code, but I am not picky on the implementation. My application requires me to remove pins. Given your advice on feasibility of regex in this case, I will likely adapt your code using an int index instead of a foreach-esq loop with a nested loop (inside loop only runs when "+" is first char and seeks backwards using the index) such that I can get the exact original instance and call netlist.replace(original_cell_instantiation, new_cell_instantiation).

Comment: Yeah, I gathered my code would not necessarily provide exactly what you need, but as long as you can adapt it, ts'all good, man :)